# How are the 4 molecules of O2 bonded in the O8 molecule at low temperature and high pressure to form a rectangular box structure?

Tags: bond

[image] 1. List item
The discovers of O8 admitted to not knowing nor understanding the bonding in O8 at very low temperatures and high pressure. They concluded that O8 was a retangular box, not a cube & that this allotrope of oxygen was composed of 4 normal O2 molecules...

Comment: Should the bonding be sp2 or sp3 or can the bond angles be 90 degrees as depicted in the retangular box?  Is there considerable stress & strain in this frozen molecule?  Is there such a thing as a square molecule and are they commonplace? Where are the electron pairs located on the 8 oxygen atoms?

Comment: Will this box molecule "explode" when it is allowed to thaw with the high pressure removed? Is the bonding in this molecule like or similar to the bonding in the "Cubane" molecule? In the octaazacubane molecule?

Comment: Provide a reference?