# What bond exists in "red oxygen", and can something similar happen with hydrogen?

Tags: bond, hydrogen

"[Red oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_oxygen#Red_oxygen)" is the nickname for O$_8$. It only exists at extremely high pressures.

What kind of bond does it have? Can hydrogen theoretically have something similar at very high pressures too?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37898/how-are-the-4-molecules-of-o2-bonded-in-the-o8-molecule-at-low-temperature-and-h

Answer (score 9):

[image: Red oxygen]

That is what I found on wikipedia. It has a cubic structure and it was **not predicted** theoretically.
here the pressure is not very high but is high(10 GPa)

High-pressure studies of hydrogen typically employ a diamond anvil cell (DAC) made of two diamonds holding a few-micrometer-thick gasket containing a tiny sample of hydrogen.

These are some more images I could found of hydrogen at high pressures, but I do not think any of them are like red oxygen.

[image: hydrogen][image: hydrogen]

#### Sources

- *[Bonding, structures, and band gap closure of hydrogen at high pressures](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1209/1209.3895.pdf)*
- This is a must read: **[Solid Hydrogen at High Pressure](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/%7Egja/thermo/HydrogenGI.pdf)**

Answer (score 8):

Hydrogen forms similar clusters as cations ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_ion_cluster)).  Some do not even need high pressure.  The trihydrogen cation, with a triangular structure resembling an aromatic cyclopropenyl cation ring, is [found in interstellar space and some planetary atmospheres](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trihydrogen_cation), and the six-atom cation with its peculiar "turnstile" strcture (two triangles joined vertex to vertex and twisted 90 degrees from each other) is observed in solid hydrogen.